# Rails HABTM validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-and-belongs-to-many

Validation for HABTM is not working, I used the following code:

```
Class GroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :group_id

end
```

Does anyone have a solution as to why this is not working?

Comment: What is the error you getting? The declaration seems to be fine. How do you try to create your relations?

Comment: I don't see a HABTM relationship here? Could you please clarify the issue and what error you are seeing.

Comment: ooh yes, you're right lebreeze, it's not habtm, didn't notice that mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's probably the plural model name. Try using GroupUser instead.

EDIT

As noted in a comment above(i didn't notice at first), you say that you do a HABTM. You actually don't do that. It's more like the intermediate model of a has_many through association.